# How do I copy cells containing value only using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range ("B56:J62") which contains some empty rows.
I tried to copy using the command below but it is copying the empty rows too.
How can I copy only the rows with value within that range.

```vb
Sub Prod_Drilling_DS()
'PURPOSE: Paste to D&B Sheet
   
'Copy A Range of Data
Worksheets("Production Sheet").Range("B55:J62").Copy

'PasteSpecial Values Only
Worksheets("Production Drilling").Range("B65500").End(xlUp)(2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

'Clear Clipboard (removes "marching ants" around your original data set)
Application.CutCopyMode = False
  
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

### The solution

You can qualify the cells you want to copy with `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)`, like this:

```
Sub Prod_Drilling_DS() 
'PURPOSE: Paste to D&B Sheet

'Copy A Range of Data (copy only cells containing data)
Worksheets("Production Sheet").Range("B55:J62").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Copy

'PasteSpecial Values Only 
Worksheets("Production Drilling").Range("B65500").End(xlUp)(2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

'Clear Clipboard (removes "marching ants" around your original data set) 
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

### The reason

The relevant part of the code was in which cells to *copy*.
(In this case, you only wanted to copy cells that contain values).

You had also specified a special type of *paste*, pasting "values".

- This method of pasting converts all content (formulas and values) to values.
- That is, any formulas are replaced by their results which are then 'hard coded' in when pasted.
- Although it specifies how to paste the copied items, it does not filter which items that are to be pasted.

In order to filter what is *pasted*, in this instance you actually needed to filter what is *copied*. The above solution achieves this.

### Extending the solution

If you want to include cells with either values *or* formulas, you would need to copy cells of type `xlCellTypeConstants` and also of type `xlCellTypeFormulas`. This answer can be modified to achieve that if needed.